Replacing go_router with auto_route in widget tests
I previously used go_router for navigation on the project, and now I am replacing it with aout_route. Everything works fine except tests, I have the following ones:
extension PumpApp on WidgetTester {
  Future<void> pumpRealRouterApp(String location) async {
    return pumpWidget(
      TranslationProvider(
        child: MaterialApp.router(
          routerConfig: AppRouter.router(location),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Here the AppRouter was configured with go_router, but now when I use auto_route, I am unsure how to make this work.
